# How many balls are adjacent?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, independence

If there is an $n\times n$ grid, and an infinite number of each of $k$ different colored balls, what is the expected number of the $2n(n-1)$ inner grid lines to have a ball of the same color on either side of the line, given that any color is equally likely to be picked for a cell?

For example, R|G is not a match, B|B is. Same for vertical adjacency.

I guessed at $\frac{2n(n-1)}{k}$ as the probability of a match is $\frac1k$. Is this right?

Comment: Is there more information about the number of balls in the grid? Are all balls equally likely?

Comment: What does it mean, "on either side"? Are there just $k$ balls, or is there a ball on every grid square? Question seems to me to be fatally ambiguous.

Comment: Hint: Write the number of such pairs as a sum of indicator functions, one for each pair, and use linearity of the expectation.  Then you can likely answer your own question.

Comment: As a sidenote, this assumes each ball is chosen independently of the others (without this type of assumption, which isn't implied by your question right now, the question cannot be answered)

Comment: I think this problem is already complicated for $n=2$. You have to look at eight different configurations: $\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr},\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&a\cr},\pmatrix{a&b\cr b&c\cr},\pmatrix{a&b\cr b&a\cr},\pmatrix{a&a\cr b&c\cr},\pmatrix{a&a\cr b&b\cr},\pmatrix{a&a\cr a&b\cr},\pmatrix{a&a\cr a&a\cr}$ some of which have to be counted with multiplicity.

Comment: Have you tried to work out an exact answer for $n=2$, JMP?

Comment: @GerryMyerson; my formula seems to work for $k=1,2,3,4,5$, giving $4,2,\frac43,1,\frac45$. (I wrote a small but slow program in Excel), indicating the $X_i$ are indeed independent.

Comment: I also think the formula can be generalized to any grid-type shape using number of inner borders/number of balls.

Comment: OK, I've checked for $n=2$, and $4/k$ is right for all $k$. I'm not sure I buy the independence argument, though. If three of the four gridlines have a match, then the fourth is guaranteed to have one. But maybe @Brian has the right idea.

Comment: @GerryMyerson; but on the other hand, 2 matches and a miss guarantees a miss.

Comment: Sure. But doesn't that also argue against independence?

Comment: mh1234 ,mh34, mh23, mh13, mh14 ,mh24, mh, mh12
These are 'matches' which link to matches for n2k2. As you can see, if 123 are given, 4 is fixed, but has $E(A_4)=0.5$

Comment: In fact $A_4=A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes A_3$. ($\otimes$ is bitwise XOR)

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate the $2n(n-1)$ inner grid lines and, for $1 \leq i \leq 2n(n-1)$, let $A_i$ denote the event that the color of the two balls adjacent the $i$th grid line have the same color.

Then the total number of inner grid lines to have a ball of the same color on either side of the line is given by the sum of indicator functions,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n(n-1)} \mathbf{1}_{A_i},$$
and we want to find the expected value of this:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{2n(n-1)} \mathbf{1}_{A_i}\right] = \sum_{i=1}^{2n(n-1)} \mathbb{E}\left[\mathbf{1}_{A_i}\right] = \sum_{i=1}^{2n(n-1)} \mathbb{P}\left[A_i\right].$$

---

At this point, under the assumption that every ball is equally likely to be one of $k$ colors and any two adjacent balls' colors are independent, we have $\mathbb{P}[A_i] = 1/k$ for any $i$.

Putting this into the above sum gives
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n(n-1)}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{2n(n-1)}{k}$$
as you had guessed.